# Q: “the pom for XXX is missing, no dependency information available”，but the dependency is already in the Nexus repository

Tags: maven, nexus

while running mvn packaging, there is a warming shown in log.

```
[WARNING] The POM for com.yueyue:order-search-interface:jar:1.2.1.SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
```

and the compiling is failed in the end with the error as following.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project dispatch-admin: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.yueyue:dispatch-admin:jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.yueyue:order-search-interface:jar:1.2.1.SNAPSHOT in bailongma_repo2 (http://192.168.200.224:8081/repository/bailongma_repo2/) -> [Help 1]
```

but the dependency is already in the maven-snapshots which is in the "bailongma_repo2" group repo.
[image]

by the way, this dependency is also in a remote repo which is as a proxy repo "aliyun_snapshot2" in "bailongma_repo2" group repo. the structure of "bailongma_repo2" group repo is as following.

[image]

what should i check first for this problem? many thanks in advance!

Comment: Provide maven log.

Comment: Have you checked the coordinates of the requested artifact? `com.yueyue:order-search-interface:jar:1.2.1.SNAPSHOT`? Check your pom files etc.

Comment: @khmarbaise yes, that should be the reason. the dependency in pom is end of ".SNAPSHOT", but in the repo is end of "-SNAPSHOT"